# cv2 resize gives unwanted artifacts

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, interpolation

I have a high resolution image with a size of 1024x1024.

[image: High resolution image]

I am trying to downscale it to 256x256 with a code below but it gives unwanted artifacts in the top row.

Here is the python code I tried.

```
img = np.array(Image.open('image.png'))
res = cv2.resize(img, dsize=(256, 256), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

[image: Resized image by INTER_AREA]

Lanczos gives the same results below.

```
img = np.array(Image.open('image.png'))
res = cv2.resize(img, dsize=(256, 256), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)
```

[image: Resized image by INTER_LANCZOS4]

How should I remove this artifacts?

Comment: why are your "downscaled" images in a higher resolution (1640x1640) than the input?

Comment: can you share the original downscaled images (256x256) saved as png?

Comment: tested it myself. By upscaling after downscaling you amplify the "cloud" artifacts which are already present in the original high resolution image. The downscaled images (with INTER_AREA) (without upscaling again) look ok to me, in similar quality as the original image.

Comment: looks like there is a limit at about 300x300 pixel downscaling for that image. If you go lower, you loose too much information for a good upscaling.

Comment: sampling theorem. your images contain high frequency features. either lowpass or accept the artefacts.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Do you mean I should blur the hr image and then downscale it?

Comment: lowpass: yes. -- also read up on gamma mapping. assuming values to be linear when they aren't will cause distorted brightness near edges. -- lowpass: INTER_AREA kinda does that already. it sums all source pixels contributing to a destination pixel. -- LANCZOS4 _also_ has a substantial support region for each destination pixel but it *does not* lowpass, so it's almost like point sampling. -- you could just use `pyrDown` twice. that includes a suitable lowpass before subsampling: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMRS5.png